# nls geom_smooth with scale_x_reverse

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls

I'm using nls with `geom_smooth` as below. This works fine

```
ggplot(model.data, aes(x=T, y=Value)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour=as.factor(Year)), size = 1) +
    geom_smooth(method = "nls", formula = y ~ a * (1 - exp(-b * x)), method.args = list(start = c(a=-2000,b=0.005)), se=FALSE, size=2, color='Grey')
```

But I also want to reverse the x-axis so I add

```
scale_x_reverse()
```

This then results in errors from nls, i.e.

> Warning message: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: number of
>   iterations exceeded maximum of 50

So it appears that `scale_x_reverse()` is transforming the x values passed to `geom_smooth()`? How can I express the model so it works regardless of the axis transformation?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem using the `mtcars` data frame. It will be easier to help you if you provide a sample of `model.data`. Paste into your question the output of `dput(model.data)`. It doesn't have to be the whole data frame, but the data sample should produce the same error you're getting.

Comment: It looks like you are getting a "warning" not an "error". Is it still plotting it ?

Comment: One solution is to pre-calculate the model fit, make predictions and then use geom_line to plot these

Comment: @steveb it's not plotting, sometimes I get an error sometimes a warning. Basically once the scale_x_reverse() is added nls fails to converge and nothing is plotted

Comment: @Richard Telford thanks, yes I've done that but I was trying to understand a little more what's going on and is there a general way of dealing with this  issue

Comment: @aosmith thanks, I'll look into that

Comment: @eipi10 I'll try and create a reproducible sample